# How can I address "ng-model" attribute to find elements on a web page?

Tags: selenium, find, element, angular-ngmodel

I am trying to use Selenium, and the only thing that I found in some elements to address is their `ng-model = "something"` attribute. But I don't know how to address them in the following code?

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome("chromedriver.exe")
search = driver.find_element_by_('')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [XPath Locator](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html#locating-by-xpath) like:

```
search = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@ng-model='something']")
```

More information:

- [XPath Tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_intro.asp)
- [`find_element_by_xpath` function reference](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.find_element_by_xpath)
- [XPath Operators & Functions](https://docs.experitest.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=40044727)